# What statistical test should I use between two scenarios?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, t-test

Scenario: I have a test data of response time of two websites in two different servers. Let's say website A and website B are tested on server A and server B not respectively but website A and website B in server A and again website A and website B in Server B. I have got a result for server A for two websites and for server B. Now let's say I want to compare the response time between these two websites by looking at the data collected from both server A and server B. I mean to say: can I combine data from server A and server B so that I can analyse the combined data for these two websites?

Example:

**Server A:**

```
For website A

    Thread  # response time
    100      1.9
    200      3.8
    300      5.7
    400      7.4
    500      9.50
    600      7.60
    700      13.30
    800      1.60
    900      1.80
    1000     20.0

    For website B

    Thread  # response time
    100      5.5
    200      9.8
    300      1.7
    400      3.4
    500      1.50
    600      3.60
    700      6.30
    800      11.60
    900      2.80
    1000     2.0
```

**Server B:**

```
For website A
Thread  # response time
100      1.9
200      3.8
300      4.7
400      3.4
500      6.50
600      6.60
700      5.30
800      13.60
900      11.80
1000     20.0

For website B

Thread  # response time
100      2.5
200      3.8
300      7.7
400      7.4
500      5.50
600      7.60
700      3.30
800      11.60
900      12.80
1000     3.0
```

So here what I want to do is rather than saying is there a difference in response time between website A and website B in server A or server B, I want to combine data from server A and server B so that I want to test this hypothesis - Is there a difference in response time for website A and website B.

Threads are the users. There are 10 iterations carried out for each websites and in every successive iteration 100 users are added. So the response time is the average response time for each iteration.

What should I do in this case, what kind of statistical analysis shall I do in order to find differences between these two websites? Is there any possibility where I can find the significant diffence by looking at both server A an server B?

Note: since the data is very small, i cannot do a frequency analysis and convert these data into frequency table.
Many thanks

Comment: It looks like the performance of Website A on Server A vs Server B is the same. And the performance of Website B on Server A vs Server B is also the same. So you have duplicate data. So the servers are irrelevant. If you just want to examine the difference between Website A and Website B, run an Independent Samples t-test. And independent Samples t-test assumes the values in the two groups are normally distributed - if this assumption is violated, run a Mann Whitney test.

Comment: Well thats only for example, i copied and pasted the same for both servers. Ill amend it again

Comment: Do you have individual response times for each request from each thread/user? And does each thread send only one request? If not, I assume each test is run with the same request/second rate and for the same length of time?

Comment: response time is the average response time for each thread... each thread has 100 users and in each iteration 100 users are added succesively